# Setting default input for a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, gnome-terminal

I am running a bash script that asks me a username and a password every time it executes.I want to keep the default as **Arjun, *(^%567590ihyg**. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You really shouldn't edit your question to mean something entirely different.

Comment: I edited the question.please check again.sry for the inconvenience

Comment: The duplicate still applies, though.

Comment: I really hope `*(^%567590ihyg` isn't your password...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not strictly about a programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use:

```
: "${x:=the_default_value}"
```

to set `x` to the string `the_default_value` if it's empty or unset.

The syntax is POSIX and is documenting along with related syntaxes at
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 .

In your case, you can attempt to read the variable or get it through a positional argument:

```
read name #or name=$1
```

and then default it if it is empty like so:

```
: "${name:=Arjun}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir:)
and please upvote the ques

Comment: @Ramesh Please upvote the ans? :)

Comment: Please don't solicit upvotes - you'll get them if your question/answer merits it.